# if input type not empty add a css style

Tags: jquery

I want to check input text direct on load page but without adding anything in input his doesn't work. how fix it?

```
<form action="">
  <input type="text" id="author" value="Bill">
</form>

$("#author").keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val()) {
        $("#author").addClass("notempty");
        /* if input is not empty do background yellow */
    } else {
        $("#author").addClass("empty");
         /* else background is red */
    }
});
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/540dwmcn/

Comment: Should be noted that you could just do `$(this).toggleClass('color', this.value.length)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is set to trigger on the keyup event. To have it also be run when the page loads, trigger the keyup manually by adding `.keyup();` on the end.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/540dwmcn/2/)**

Also, you probably want to clear the classes as well (note the use of `.removeClass()` in the fiddle)

```
$("#author").keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val()) {
        $("#author").removeClass().addClass("notempty");
        /* if input is not empty do background yellow */
    } else {
        $("#author").removeClass().addClass("empty");
        /* else background is red */
    }
}).keyup();
```

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/540dwmcn/4/)

```
$("#author").keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val()) {
        $("#author").addClass("notempty")
        .removeClass("empty");
        /* if input is not empty do background yellow */
    } else {
        $("#author").addClass("empty")
        .removeClass("notempty");
        /* else background is red */
    }
}).keyup();
```